# How do I add a feature for a customizable product?

Tags: wordpress, web

I am a trainer customiser and I am trying to set up my own website.
What I am looking for is a feature that allows the customer to customise different parts of the shoe with different colours and for them to have a preview of how it will look. Something similar to Nike ID or https://mattbcustoms.com/apps/zakeke?pid=4739886547019.
I am not the most advanced at coding so this has truly got my mind baffled on where to even start!
Can someone please help!

I didn't know where to start. My website that I am creating is currently on Wordpress.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will get some well known premium plugins that may fulfill your requirements.
Like [Fancy Product Designer](https://codecanyon.net/item/fancy-product-designer-woocommercewordpress/6318393)

If you want to build it by own custom coding then you can go with HTML canvas, fabric js.